# Android - there is an unwanted black border in the whole app for each layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

This is the code for a fragment layout which is attached in a activity.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_property_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/NavBarColor"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ham_menu_icon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_menu"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

            <com.instaoffice.android.views.InstaTextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ham_menu_icon"
                android:textColor="@color/NavBarTextColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="ALL OFFICES"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<fr.castorflex.android.circularprogressbar.CircularProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pl_loader"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    app:cpb_color="@color/tealPrimary"
    app:cpb_rotation_speed="1.0"
    app:cpb_sweep_speed="1.0"
    app:cpb_stroke_width="3dp"
    app:cpb_min_sweep_angle="10"
    app:cpb_max_sweep_angle="300" />

<com.instaoffice.android.views.GlobalRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/pl_rv"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code for the activity in which the fragment is being attached :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:background="@color/dirty_purple"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/am_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_pl"
       android:name="com.instaoffice.android.fragments.PropertyListFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_property_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/root_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: The black margin from all the 4 sides comes in some]

of the 1440*2560 resolution devices like samsung , le-eco.

What's wrong in the layout i am not able to figure it out . Please help

Comment: Have you tried setting the margin to 0?

Comment: yes @user6547359 i tired  and it did not change anything ,same result.

Comment: it is a fragment right? Can you also post the XML in which you are placing it?

Comment: yes its a fragment, sure @user6547359

Comment: @user6547359 please check the question , i have added the activity XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the App theme which i had defined in the styles.xml. I had attached a layer background in the app theme with this line of code :

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_layer</item>
```

I just removed it and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your coordinatorLayout: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`